# Replacing postgresql.conf in a docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, unix, docker-entrypoint, postgresql-12

I am pulling the postgres:12.0-alpine docker image to build my database. My intention is to replace the postgresql.conf file in the container to reflect the changes I want (changing data directory, modify backup options etc). I am trying with the following docker file

```
FROM postgres:12.0-alpine

# create the custom user 
RUN addgroup -S custom && adduser -S custom_admin -G custom

# create the appropriate directories 
ENV APP_HOME=/home/data 
ENV APP_SETTINGS=/var/lib/postgresql/data 
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# copy entrypoint.sh 
COPY ./entrypoint.sh $APP_HOME/entrypoint.sh

# copy postgresql.conf 
COPY ./postgresql.conf $APP_HOME/postgresql.conf

RUN chmod +x /home/data/entrypoint.sh

# chown all the files to the app user 
RUN chown -R custom_admin:custom $APP_HOME 
RUN chown -R custom_admin:custom $APP_SETTINGS

# change to the app user 
USER custom_admin

# run entrypoint.sh 
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/data/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["custom_admin"]
```

my entrypoint.sh looks like

```
#!/bin/sh

rm /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
cp ./postgresql.conf /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf

echo "replaced .conf file"

exec "$@"
```

But I get an exec error saying 'custom_admin: not found on the 'exec "$@"' line. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

In order to provide a custom configuration. Please use the below command:

```
docker run -d --name some-postgres -v "$PWD/my-postgres.conf":/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf postgres -c 'config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf'
```

Here `my-postgres.conf` is your custom configuration file.

Refer the [docker hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) for more information about the postgres image.

Comment: This does not work for changing directory. The directory needs to have appropriate privileges which are not working according to the #2 and #3 of the "Arbitrary --user Notes" on the docker hub page. Did you have any success running the postgres container as a different user?

Comment: @neoceph Why do you want to run it as different user? I haven't faced any permission denied issue while using a different config file.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use the suggested answer by @Thilak, you do not need custom image to just use the custom config.

Now the problem with the `CMD ["custom_admin"]` in the Dockerfile, any command that is passed to `CMD` in the Dockerfile, you are executing that command in the end of the entrypoint, normally such command refers to main or long-running process of the container. Where `custom_admin` seems like a user, not a command. you need to replace this with the process which would run as a main process of the container.

Change CMD to

```
CMD ["postgres"]
```

I would suggest modifying the [offical entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/0d0485cb02e526f5a240b7740b46c35404aaf13f/9.5/alpine/docker-entrypoint.sh) which do many tasks out of the box, as you own entrypoint just starting the container no DB initialization etc.